# Integrate AMERICAN EXPRESS payment source with django-oscar 0.6

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-oscar

I'm doing an e-commerce website which use django-oscar 0.6. I have to integrate AMERICAN EXPRESS payment source with this project. Is there any existing packages available already like django-oscar-paypal, or i have to build a new app from the scratch. I tried searching all over the internet but code for python and django was not found.

Comment: You have to write it yourself. Start [here](https://gateway-na.americanexpress.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/directPayment/integrationModelDirectPayment.html?locale=en_US)

Comment: you can use authorize.net API too

Answer (score 0):

Try sagepay-payment-gateway. It can be integrated with your E-commerse. It supports AMERICAN EXPRESS  too

http://sagepay-payment-gateway-package-for-django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html